# How to assign value to Lastrow and Firstrow parameter using some variable in BULK INSERT?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand VARCHAR(MAX) DECLARE @NAME varchar (100)
DECLARE @FIRSTROW INT,@LASTROW INT
SET @FIRSTROW =
  (SELECT TOP 1 [Id]
   FROM [dbo].[TableB]
   ORDER BY [Id] DESC) + 1
SET @LASTROW = @FIRSTROW + 4
SELECT @NAME =
  (SELECT 'C:\InsertTestdata.txt')
SET NOCOUNT ON;


SET @sqlCommand = 'BULK INSERT [dbo].[TableA] FROM ''' + @NAME + '''
                            WITH (DATAFILETYPE = ''char'',
                            FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
                            ROWTERMINATOR = '''+CHAR(10)+''',
                            FIRSTROW = 2,
                            LASTROW = '''+ @LASTROW +'''
                            );' 
EXEC (@sqlCommand);
```

I am getting error while executing above script
Anyone can explain what is the right way to give Lastrow and firstrow parameters using some variable in Bulk Insert Statement?

Comment: `I am getting error while executing above script` what is the error?

Comment: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'BULK INSERT [dbo].[TableA] FROM 'C:\InsertTestData.txt'
      WITH (DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
      FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
      ROWTERMINATOR = '
',
      FIRSTROW = '' to data type int.

Comment: try converting all the ints in your query to varchar ..ex:` 2`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand VARCHAR(MAX) DECLARE @NAME varchar (100)
DECLARE @FIRSTROW INT,@LASTROW INT
SET @FIRSTROW = 4
  --(SELECT TOP 1 [Id]
  -- FROM [dbo].[TableB]
  -- ORDER BY [Id] DESC) + 1
SET @LASTROW = @FIRSTROW + 4
SELECT @NAME =
  (SELECT 'C:\InsertTestdata.txt')
SET NOCOUNT ON;


SET @sqlCommand = concat('BULK INSERT [dbo].[TableA] FROM ''' , @NAME , '''
                            WITH (DATAFILETYPE = ''char'',
                            FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
                            ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',
                            FIRSTROW = 2,
                            LASTROW = ', @LASTROW ,'
                            );' );
print @sqlCommand;
```

outputs

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[TableA] FROM 'C:\InsertTestdata.txt'
                            WITH (DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
                            FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
                            ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
                            FIRSTROW = 2,
                            LASTROW = 8
                            );
```

Comment: Firstrow is going to vary

Comment: You know how to assign a variable to a value from a table.